# How to crop a selected image and save that cropped image to a folder using php

Tags: php, jquery, html, save, jcrop

I am using Jcrop plugin to crop an image.

I upload my photo with a standard html form.
I show my last uploaded image with the following code:

```
 <img id="cropbox" src="<?php echo $target ?>" width="400" />
```

This looks like the following:[image]

My code for $target looks like this:

```
 <?php 
     $target = "uploads/"; 
     $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['filename']['name']) ; 
     $ok=1; 
     if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
     {
     echo "De afbeelding *". basename( $_FILES['filename']['name']). "* is geupload naar de map 'uploads'";
     } 
     else {
     echo "Sorry, er is een probleem met het uploaden van de afbeelding.";
     }
 ?>
```

Now i can start selecting my area to crop:[image]

Now i want to save the selected crop area to a new jpg image using the following code:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    $targ_w = 200;
    $targ_h = 400;
    $jpeg_quality = 90;

    $src = '';
    $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
    $dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );

    imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],
    $targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);

    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    imagejpeg($dst_r,NULL,$jpeg_quality);

    exit;
}

?>
```

My question is now, how do i use that $target Source i used to show the image i just uploaded in that php code above?

I have no idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the path to file into $_SESSION when uploading the target. In your uploaded.php use this code (here you start the session with session_start() and put the formed target path to $_SESSION array):

```
 <?php 
 session_start();
 $target = "uploads/"; 
 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['filename']['name']) ; 
 $_SESSION['target_path'] = $target;

 $ok=1; 
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
 {
 echo "De afbeelding *". basename( $_FILES['filename']['name']). "* is geupload naar de map 'uploads'";
 } 
 else {
 echo "Sorry, er is een probleem met het uploaden van de afbeelding.";
 }
?>
```

In your crop.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
$targ_w = 200;
$targ_h = 400;
$jpeg_quality = 90;

$src = $_SESSION['target_path'];
$img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
$dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );

imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],
$targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($dst_r,NULL,$jpeg_quality);

exit;
}

?>
```

Comment: can you explain this further? i don't fully understand how to do this

Comment: I have expanded my post to describe what you need to do more detailed

Comment: it worked. thanks! :D now i can go on with my project! +1 and accepted

Answer (score 0):

You need to either reload the page with new image URL specified, or return that URL back to JavaScript so your JS code could replace image without reloading.

Comment: i am redirecting to a new page when i click 'Crop Image' i am redirecting to crop.php, and when i click on 'Crop Image' i am on uploaded.php

Answer (score 0):

[imagejpeg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) takes a filename parameter which you have set to NULL.

You can use this to store the cropped image to disk on the server and then load it up again when you redirect to a "showimage.php" or whatever result page you have. You can redirect using a Location header.

You can keep track of the image path across reloads/redirects using some sort of database, or if this is a quick project, just store the image path in a cookie / session variable.